# GORMless Grails app fails looking for missing (and unnecessary) transactionManager

Tags: spring, grails

My Grails 2.1 app is blowing up on launch, with the BeanCreationException below, when it tries to instatiate a Grails service called `ServiceParamService`. I'm not surprised it's not finding a transaction manager but I don't see why it's looking for one.

Poking around in the debugger, it looks like it's decided that the `ServiceParamService` is something called a `"TypeSpecifyableTransactionProxyFactoryBean"`, which, by its nature, takes the parameters `target`, `proxyTargetClass`, `transactionAttributeSource` and `transactionManager`.

What's weird is that this service instantiates just fine in another Grails app that also doesn't have a transaction manager defined, and which has an identical `Config.groovy`, `BuildConfig.groovy`, and `resources.xml`. So somehow, by dumb luck, the other app gets around this. Short of throwing the new app out (and starting over by deleting 90% of the old), how can I figure out what the old app's doing to get around this bogus transaction manager requirement? And/or get around it myself?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceParamService': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:130)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:269)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 49 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are transactional by default. Add

```
static transactional = false
```

to your service class to keep it from being wrapped in a transactional proxy.

Comment: That works, but I can't figure out why it worked without that in the other project. Is there a global default somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure why it would work in the other app. The default has always been like that and there's no global setting to enable or disable it. We did originally include the line `static transactional = true` in generated services but removed it since it was redundant to set it to the default.

Comment: Does the other application have a `DataSource.groovy`? Removing that might remove the need to set the `transactional` value.